# Hadoop installation : configuring Namenode failure

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Trying to format the NameNode to create a Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) using below command:

```
$ bin/hadoop namenode –format
```

and the error while executing the commnad:

```
bin/hadoop: line 351: -Xmx32m: command not found
bin/hadoop: line 435: exec: : not found
```

Comment: What shell are you using to execute the above command ?

Comment: Which version of Hadoop?
Have you set all environment variables?

Comment: Hi Both, I am using Cygwin. As suggested in http://saphanatutorial.com/hadoop-installation-on-windows/#